# textfield on alert view issue of key board dismiss

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uialertview

i have critical problem in my code, i have 3 textField in alert view, 2 times i tap the text field and press ok button of alert view keyboard resign, but third time its not dismissed.

[Here my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652352/resign-keyboard-of-textfield-present-in-alertview)

Comment: Share the code where you resign the keyboard.

Comment: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{
    if (alertView.tag==1)
        
    {
        [self.utextfield resignFirstResponder];
        [self.ptextfield resignFirstResponder];
        [self.ptextfieldInches resignFirstResponder];
    }
    
}

Comment: Your code should work.. Better do check your alert tag.. Else do like this..  in textFieldBeginEditing method get that textfield and assign it to one global textfield like ActiveTextfield = textField.  Then in alertview delegate resign that ActiveTextfield.

Answer (score 0):

Add action to textfield for hide keyboard like followings:

```
 [ptextfield
 addTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

and for hiding keyboard:

```
- (void)hideKeyboard:(id)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: i have been reding that, your app will getv rejected if you will use textfilds in alert view is it true

Comment: If you use addTextFieldWithValue method, your app will be rejected. Because it is undocumented. Since iOS 5 apple supports customization for UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.. Better do check your alert tag.. Else do like this..  in 
`textFieldBeginEditing`
 method get that textfield and assign it to one global textfield like

`ActiveTextfield = textField`.

Then in alertview delegate resign that ActiveTextfield.

Answer (score 0):

I put my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652352/resign-keyboard-of-textfield-present-in-alertview). Please check. You don't need to open too many questions about a single thing.